# Genereting a list from dask - getting value error

Tags: dask

We have a `dask DataFrame` as follows:

```
ID  listNum
1  [a,b]
2  [a,b,c]
3  [d,e,f,g]
```

Which needs to be transformed to

```
ID  listNum
1  [a,b]
2  [a,b]
2  [b,c]
2  [a,c]
3  [d,e]  
3  [d,f]  
3  [d,g]  
3  [e,f]     
3  [e,g]     
3  [f,g]
```

In `Pandas` the following code works

```
list_combine=[x, list(i) for x,y in df[['ID', 'listNum']].values 
                         for i in list(itertools.combinations(y,2))]
df_combinations = pd.DataFrame(data=[(idx, num[0], num[1]) for idx, num in list_combine]
                                  , columns=['idx', 'num1', 'num2'])
```

When running the list_combine line on the `dask.DataFrame`  we get the following error:

```
list_combine=[x, y for x,y in df[['ID', 'listNum']].values]
`ValueError: ('Arrays chunk sizes are unknown: %s', (nan,2) )`
```

I guess there is a need to convert the `dask.dataframe` into a [dask.array](http://dask.pydata.org/en/latest/array-creation.html) and then recreate the `dask.dataframe`

Currently our solution is to convert it into a list and then use a `Pandas.Dataframe`

```
list_combine=[x, list(i) for x,y in df[['ID', 'listNum']].compute().values 
                             for i in list(itertools.combinations(y,2))]
```

Is there a better way to generate the final desired dataframe?

Answer (score 0):

I would apply your Pandas function onto your dask dataframe using [map_partitions](http://dask.pydata.org/en/latest/dataframe-api.html#dask.dataframe.DataFrame.map_partitions)

```
def your_function(df):
    list_combine=[x, list(i) for x,y in df[['ID', 'listNum']].values 
                             for i in list(itertools.combinations(y,2))]
    df_combinations = bpd.DataFrame(data=[(idx, num[0], num[1]) for idx, num in list_combine]
                                      , columns=['idx', 'num1', 'num2'])
    return df_combinations

ddf = ddf.map_partitions(your_function, meta=ddf._meta)
```

Although, as a warning, Pandas/Dask are not as efficient with list dtypes than with scalar types.

Comment: Thx, is there a way to retain a dask.dataframe (instead of the `pd.DataFrame`)?

Comment: In the above, `ddf` is a `dask.dataframe`.